# Redirecting to login screen on logout with $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular application I use $stateProvider to allow the user access different options. One of these options is `Logout`, where the intent is to replace the current screen with the login screen.

This is how I use the provider:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('option1', {
      url: "/option1",
      templateUrl: "assets/app/web/option1.html"
    })
   // other options ....
```

For the logout option, I don't have a screen, so there's no templateUrl (the screen should be the login screen, that has its own controller to handle the login). I tried the `redirectTo` attribute but I don't know how to assign it a controller. Any ideas?

Comment: Just add a controller to that logout state, and inject `$state` into it. Do your stuff inside the controller, and redirect the user using `$state.go('MyState', {my: options});`

Comment: If you must use a template (Not sure if you do) - Than provide an empty and basic template like `template: '<ui-view/>'` (For example)

Comment: thanks, I don't need the template. Instead of doing `$state.go` I used `$window.location.replace('/login');` to avoid the user going back to the application page, any issues?

Comment: *"any issues"* better to use `$state.go()` but overall I don't understand why you would need an option url for login anyway so to me it makes far more sense going to /login`

Comment: you can do `$state.go('MyState', {my: options}, {location: 'replace');` for that [reference](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)